# RequestAnimationFrame execute method only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gamepad

**Background information**:
I am trying to make an application with ElectronJS. The backend is a python webserver which starts at the same time electron starts.

I will refer to the python webserver as "the backend" and ElectronJS as "the frontend".

**Problem**:
The animation frame needs to execute a callback to the python webserver which executes a system process. At this time the gamepad button is registered multiple times and executes the request to the backend many times.

**Desired behavior**:
What i want is the requestanimationframe not to respond to consecutive keypresses from the gamepad until the function has finished.

**What i have tried**:
Below i have two of the code samples i have tried. There are many more which i have tried, but do not remember. Does anyone have a solution to my problem as described, or a way to get the desired behavior?

**Code samples of my attempts**

```
 var respondToButton = true;

function scanInput()
{

    var gp = false;

    if (navigator.getGamepads()[0]) {
        gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0];

        if (respondToButton){

            if(gp.buttons[14].pressed) {
                respondToButton = false;
                control.next(1)
                respondToButton = true;
            };

        }
    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
```

### Second try

```
 var animationFrameID;

function scanInput()
{

    var gp = false;

    if (navigator.getGamepads()[0]) {
        gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0];

            if(gp.buttons[14].pressed) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameID);
                control.next(1)
                animationFrameID = window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
            };


    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
```

**Edit**
At this moment i am looking at javascript promises, but i cannot seem to grasp the concept properly. What is the simplest form of a promise? I see many different implementations around the web.

**Edit 1**
Tried a new way with promises, but this also does not provide the preferred behavior.

```
    function scanInput() {

    if (navigator.getGamepads()[0]) {
        var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0];

            switch(true){

                case gp.buttons[0].pressed:
                    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        resolve(control.enter());
                    });
                    promise.then(function(result){
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
                    });
                    break;

                case gp.buttons[1].pressed:
                    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        resolve(control.back());
                    });
                    promise.then(function(result){
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
                    });
                    break;

                case gp.buttons[13].pressed:
                    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        resolve(control.prev(1));
                    });
                    promise.then(function(result){
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
                    });
                    break;

                case gp.buttons[14].pressed:
                    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        resolve(control.next(1));
                    });
                    promise.then(function(result){
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
                    break;
            }
    }
};
window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
```

Comment: At this moment i am reading about JS promises. It seems promising ;) and might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're resolving the promises instantly. Looking at the Promise docs, the `function(resolve, reject)` is run instantly, and so you're thereby calling `resolve()` instantly.

I don't know what the implementations of `control.next` etc. look like, but they themselves would need to return a promise (that's resolved only when it's "done"), and then you could do:

```
control.next(1)
.then(function(result){
     window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
})
```

You could also use callbacks instead of promises by making the `control` functions take a function as the last argument (called when they're "done"), and calling them like:

```
control.next(1, function(){
     window.requestAnimationFrame(scanInput);
})
```

That said, it sounds like you're doing HTTP requests on every button press. There are better ways to do this: [socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io) is a nice option. There's even a [python server implementation](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio), but I'd recommend using [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) unless you have complicated logic already written in Python. You shouldn't need to worry so much about sending multiple requests, because they can be tiny fast messages instead.

Some notes:

- You need to check if `navigator.getGamepad` itself exists to actually detect gamepad support without getting an error when there isn't support.
- You don't need to provide a value to a variable you're declaring. By default it'll get the value `undefined`, and `undefined` or `null` are both better values to use for "no object (yet)" than a Boolean like `false`. (You can also just do `var gp =` within the `if` block; `var` declarations don't have to be at the top of a function.)